# Output last 5 rows in database [CakePHP]

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have a database and I want to output the last 5 rows on the database. The model is called 
'text'.

```
<?php for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) { 

    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $text['Text']['id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $text['Text']['expiration']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $text['Text']['title'] . " - " . $text['Text']['body']; ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $text['Text']['created']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

That should give you an idea of where I'm at.

Comment: You can use `Order desc` and `limit 5` in find method in cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`find()`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/449/find)

Other way is to use [`query()`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/view/456/query)

```
$alltext = $this->Text->find('all', array('limit' => 5,'order'=>array('id DESC')));
<?php foreach ($alltextext as $text): ?>
 // format as necessary
<td><?php echo $text['Text']['id']; ?></td> 
// add others here
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: The closest I can get is this: 

$results = $this->Text->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id),
            'order' => 'id DESC'
            ));

Comment: I put this in to try it out, and it didn't work: 

<?php 
 $alltext = $this->Text->find('all', array('limit' => 5,'order'=>array('id DESC')));
foreach ($alltext as $text): ?>

<td><?php echo $text['Text']['id']; ?></td> 

<?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: @DCo Make the `find()` in controller and [set](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/979/set) it in controller. This set variable can be accessed in view(ctp).